# ClassNotFoundException exception with redisson

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I'm trying to use a RSet to store my ranks, but I have a ClassNotFoundException while the class exists (I even decompiled and the class is here). In my opinion Redisson cannot store a custom object class?
Here is my code:

```java
public class RedisProvider {

    private final RSet<Rank> ranks;
    private final RedissonClient client;


    public RedisProvider() {
        this.client = Redisson.create();
        this.ranks = client.getSet("ranks");
        Rank rank = new Rank("default", 0, "&7", "&7");
        addRank(rank);
    }

    public Set<Rank> getRanks(){
        return ranks.readAll();
    }


    public void addRank(Rank rank) {
        ranks.add(rank);
    }

}
```

Error:

```
[17:51:39 ERROR]: Unable to decode data. channel: [id: 0xb12f3447,
L:/127.0.0.1:58768 - R:127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:6379], reply:
ReplayingDecoderByteBuf(ridx=146, widx=146), command: (SSCAN), promise:
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@4e7fd89e[Not completed, 1
dependents], params: [ranks, 0, COUNT, 10] java.io.IOException:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.rhodless.test.Rank
```

I checked if the "Rank" class existed and it exists.

Comment: I also have similar issue.